# bind read-only data to another model

Tags: ember.js

I have a survey app with a model to store questions and its choices:

```
/models/question.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
     text: DS.attr(),
     choices: DS.attr(),
});
```

using `mirage-fixtures` to store these questions as follow:

```
export default [{
    id: '1',
    text: 'What is your name\'s first letter?',
    choices: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  }, { ... }
```

And I have another model to store records:

```
/models/answer.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
     submittedAt: DS.attr(),
     questions: DS.hasMany('question')
});

/routes/answer.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
     return this.get('store').createRecord('answer', { submittedAt: new Date() });
  },
});
```

Also I am using [ember-radio-button](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button), as an easier way to deal with radio buttons. Hooking a component for question in a nested route that call a question.

```
/routes/answer/question.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.get('store').find('question', params.question_id)
  }
});

/templates/answer/question.hbs
 {{model.text}}
 {{#each model.choices as |choice|}}
    {{#radio-button
      value=choice
      groupValue=question
      changed=selected
      }}
        {{choice}}
    {{/radio-button}}
  {{/each}}

/components/a-question.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        selected(choice) {
          console.log('Current choice is: ', choice);
          this.set('question', choice);
        }
      }
});
```

So how can I store selected choices of each question in answer data?